# drawableEnd textview property not working in mobile android

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-drawable, xml-drawable

Hello friends I want to my drawable image to end of my `textview` so i set my layout as below

**xml file**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_four"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_two"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Go ahead and get to the area you want then"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/alogo_small"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```

when i run above code it shoe me output like below

[image]

I want my drawable after `then` so any idea how can I solve this problem ? Your all suggestion are appreciable

**EDIT**

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Go ahead and get to the area you want then"); 
     Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.alogo_small); 
     d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
     ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); 
     ss.setSpan(span, ss.length(), ss.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
     mTextViewEmailTwo.setText(ss);
```

when I run above code it give me output like below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use  Html.ImageGetter:

```
Html.ImageGetter getter = new Html.ImageGetter(){
     public Drawable getDrawable(String source){   // source is the resource name
     Drawable d = null;
     Integer id =  new Integer(0);
     id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable",getPackageName());

     d = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(id);

     if (d != null)
         d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
         return d;
     }
};

String imgString = "Go ahead and get to the area you want then " + " <img src=\"alogo_small\"/>";
mTextViewEmailTwo.setText(Html.fromHtml(imgString, getter, null));
```

Comment: Haresh Chhelana : what is value for `is`,  `index`, `strLength`?